# Number picker in android not showing properly

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview, numberpicker

I'm starting to build an app with android studio and right away I'm having a bit of an issue.  Currently my number pickers look like this in the XML preview:

[image: preview]

But when I run the app (on the emulator) it looks like this:

[image: emulator]

There is a text view that you can't see in the preview but appears when the app is run, that is why you see the text "Time's up" in the emulator screenshot.  What I'm wondering is why are the number pickers so close to my textview and off to the left?  I don't mind the change in style (in fact I welcome it) but I can't figure out why they moved. Any help is greatly appreciated! Here is my XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.skytbest.intervaltrainer.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddinBottom="50dip"
    android:textSize="50dp"
 />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Start"    />

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timer"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"   />

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"   />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want it to look like, but the `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timer"` in your first NumberPicker is part of the problem. If you want the number pickers grouped and centered horizontally below the text label, I suggest you group the NumberPickers in a horizontal LinearLayout and tag the LinearLayout with layout_centerHorizontal.

Comment: I want it to look like it does in the AndroidStudio preview. I will try the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working layout using the suggestion in my comment. Note that it is helpful to put some text in the TextView to better enable the UI designer to show the layout. Even then it sometimes does not match what you see on screen, especially when you have invalid combinations of layout constraints.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.skytbest.intervaltrainer.MainActivity">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Label"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Start"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/timer">
    <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked, thank you! For some reason my numberpicker won't let me select any numbers though, it is locked to zero... is this default functionality?

Comment: NumberPicker is not as easy to use as it might be. Try something like this in your activity: `NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
  np.setMaxValue(100);
  np.setMinValue(0);
 `

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `setMinValue` and `setMaxValue` otherwise it will get stack on 0.